# Can I bind a WPF TextBox or other control to an IronPython property?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, ironpython

I am implementing a UserControl in IronPython. I want to bind a control to an IronPython property.  But when the binding is created, it complains:

```
Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'IronPython.Runtime.PythonProperty' and 'System.String'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=z; DataItem='OldInstance' (HashCode=27321283); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

.. and when text is entered, instead of calling the setter, it overwrites the property object with the new text.  Is there a way to make this work?  If not, what is the best alternative?

Here is my code:

```
import System
from System import Action
from System.Windows import Window
from System.Windows.Data import Binding, BindingMode
from System.Windows.Controls import StackPanel, Label, TextBox, Orientation
class xclass():
  def __init__(self):
    self.__y = "ytext"
    self.zval = "ztext"
  @property
  def y(self):
    print "get_y", self.__y
    return self.__y
  @y.setter
  def y(self, value):
    self.__y = value
    print "set_y", value
  def get_z(self):
    print "get_z", self.zval
    return self.zval
  def set_z(self, value):
    print "set_z", value
    self.zval = value
  z = property(get_z, set_z)
x = xclass()
def f():
  win = Window()
  sp = StackPanel()
  sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
  sp.Height=24
  lb = Label()
  lb.Content="Label0"
  bd1 = Binding("y")
  bd1.Source = x
  bd2 = Binding("z")
  bd2.Source = x
  tb1 = TextBox()
  tb1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bd1)
  tb2 = TextBox()
  tb2.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bd2)
  win.AddChild(sp)
  sp.AddChild(lb)
  sp.AddChild(tb1)
  sp.AddChild(tb2)
  win.Show()
  win.Width = 400
  win.Height = 200
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Action(f));
```

Answer (score 0):

xclass must inherit from System.Object!

```
class xclass(System.Object):
```

That is all.